# How to run another instance of Main() in AS3

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, instance, program-entry-point

How would you run a new instance of your Main function in AS3? Basically I want the program to rerun itself from the start, once it reaches the end of the program. I thought about removing all my childs from the tree at the end, then running the first method again, but that just seems unnecessary and messy. The class extends Sprite.

EDIT: Trying to create a Custom Event and using `dispatchEvent` to trigger this at the end of the program but having a little problem. This is my current code below.

Entire RunMain.as:

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class RunMain extends Sprite {

        public function RunMain():void {

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
        }

        private function loop(event:Event){

            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
            dispatchEvent(new EndEvent(EndEvent.END_EVENT));
        }

    }
}
```

Entire EndEvent.as:

```
package  
{
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class EndEvent extends Event 
    {
        // Event types.
        public static const END_EVENT:String = "event1";

        public function EndEvent(type:String = EndEvent.END_EVENT) 
        {
            super(type);
        }

        override public function clone():Event {
            // Return a new instance of this event with the same parameters.
            return new EndEvent(type);
        }
    }
}
```

Parts of Main.as:

```
public function Main() {
    runMain = new RunMain();
    runMain.addEventListener(EndEvent.END_EVENT, onProgramFinish);
    addChild(runMain);

    init();
    otherMethods();
}

public function onProgramFinish() {
    removeChild(runMain);

    runMain = null;

    runMain = new RunMain() ;
}
```

Inside my Main class, I have the line `onProgramFinish();` at the end of the program.

At the moment, when I run the compiler it comes up with the error:
ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on Main/onProgramFinish().
Expected 0, got 1.

When I choose to continue, the program runs fine, but it doesn't run a new instance at the end of it.

Answer (score 0):

In fact you must create a special class container and swap him (create new or delete) exactly in main class. This game class can `dispatch events`, at least sprites can dispatch events. Creating your custom events and passing them to higher and higher level will allow you to perform actions in Main class.

```
class Main extends Sprite {
  public var game:Game ;
  public function Main():void {
    game = new Game(new Player(), "asd") ;
    game.addEventListener(GameEvent.GAME_OVER, onGameOver) ;
    addChild(game) ;
  }

  public function onGameOver(){
    removeChild(game) ;
    //also you can try removing heavy children of game
    game = null ; //Let garbage collector know about object without reference.

    game = new Game(new Player(), "example") ;
  }
}

public class Game extends Sprite {

  public var hero:Hero = new Hero() ;
  public function Game(player:Player, name:String):void {

    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop) ;
  }

  private function loop(event:Event){
    if (hero.hp == 0){
      removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop) ;
      dispatchEvent(new GameEvent(GameEvent.GAME_OVER)) ;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It won't be a game but just an animation-type program. There isn't a GameEvent class that I can access in the AS3 documentation. Is there any way to do this using other types of Events built into AS3? Also, is it possible to run all this inside the Main() class document, rather than creating another class?

Comment: No that was an example. GameEvent does not exist, but you can create it. You can create ANY class, ANY program, use any type of existing events and [create your own events](http://jeffnehlsen.com/2011/02/actionscript-3-custom-events-explained/). And ofc, you can run everything in Main class, but it is supposed to messy.

Comment: Okay I see. So would the GAME_OVER be a method inside the CustomEvent?

Comment: It's a constant, usually string. You can place any constant inside your events.

Comment: I've updated my question to reflect the current situation – I've run into a little problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your event:

```
package {
    import flash.events.Event;

public class ProgramEvent extends Event 
{

    public static const FINISH:String = "Finished" ;

    public function ProgramEvent(type:String, bubbles:Boolean=false, cancelable:Boolean=false) 
    { 
        super(type, bubbles, cancelable);

    } 

    public override function clone():Event 
    { 
        return new ProgramEvent(type, bubbles, cancelable);
    } 

    public override function toString():String 
    { 
        return formatToString("ProgramEvent", "type", "bubbles", "cancelable", "eventPhase"); 
    }

}

}
```

RunMain:

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class RunMain extends Sprite {

        public function RunMain():void {

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
        }

        private function loop(event:Event){

            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
            dispatchEvent(new ProgramEvent(ProgramEvent.FINISH));
        }

    }
}
```

And Main:

```
public function Main() {
    startProgram() ;

    init();
    otherMethods();
}

public function onProgramFinish(event:ProgramEvent) {
    runMain.removeEventListener(ProgramEvent.FINISH, onProgramFinish) ;
    removeChild(runMain);
    runMain = null;
    startProgram() ;
}

public function startProgram(){
  runMain = new RunMain() ;
  runMain.addEventListener(ProgramEvent.FINISH, onProgramFinish);
  addChild(runMain);
}
```

Comment: Does this mean I should remove the `addChild(runMain);` inside `Main()`? Adding the child inside onProgramFinish comes up with error 1136: Incorrect number of arguments.  Expected 1. for the line `onProgramFinish();`

Comment: Ah that's a more OOP way of doing it, thanks. However it still comes up with the same arguments error for `onProgramFinish();` when I call it. I think I'm calling it wrong?

Comment: Also, wouldn't having `startProgram();` in both class function `Main()` and function `onProgramFinish(event:ProgramEvent)` create one extra instance (which then cannot be removed when the program finishes again)?

Comment: Do not manually call onProgramFinish, only eventListener must call it and pass Event into it. And - no, I rewrote the code, so it's called only 1 time in the beginning. So, if the code works, and you understood what i mean, would you like to accept my answer? :>

Comment: Okay, I removed the manual call. So if I understand correctly: when the program is run, startProgram() runs. This creates a new runMain with an EventListener that loops over and over again until it recognises the program has finished. When it recognises the program has finished, it dispatches the FINISH event. When this happens, onProgramFinish is run and removes the previous Listener and Child, then creates a new instance of runMain through startProgram.

Comment: What the program does right now is run up until the end, then closes itself... it doesn't actually restart or seem to create a new instance of itself. Perhaps this is because only startProgram is being run after it finishes, and only a new runMain is made? Not a new Main?

Comment: new RunMain is created. Main class is still the same. And yes, you can check conditions on the loops and dispatch event if you like to.

Comment: How can I use the current code to create a new instance of Main() when the program finishes? Basically, to "restart" the program. Right now it just closes the program automatically when it finishes.

Comment: Sorry, I'm having a bit of a brain fart moment today. Can you explain how the program "reruns" when the Main class stays the same with the current code? runMain is only creating a new instance of EventListeners, not the actual Main class.

Comment: Your Main class is not your Main program, Im telling you, that your program must be RunMain. When it finishes a new instance of RunMain is created. Not to be confused, just rename RunMain to Program.

Comment: Ah... so I should move all my otherMethods(); code which is inside Main at the moment into RunMain/Program? Then have Flash point to Main when compiling?

Comment: Okay... it's because when I do this, the program starts looping my first method over and over again without doing anything...